# Not able to attach SQL backups in tfs 2015

Tags: sql, tfs, tfs-2015

We take daily SQL backups of our TFS server Project collections. One of the collection has to be copied to new TFS server 2015. We took the backup from our daily backups, restored it from the SQL. TFS versions in both servers are same TFS 2015 Update 1 and SQL version of old TFS is SQL 2014 SP1, new TFS is SQL 2014 SP2.

However while attaching the collection from console, we get an error like [image]
Is it always to be practiced to detach the collection and copy to another server to restore it? If so why are the backups daily SQL backups useful? (supposed to be useful for disaster recovery)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the scheduled backups restore, you need to use the **Restore tool**. Just 
 start the **Restore wizard** but not copy the collection database backup directly to SQL server, see [Restore the databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs) for details. The steps vary depending on whether you need to [restore data to a new server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-home), or whether you want to [restore data to the same server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/restore-data-same-location).

You'll need to start with a machine that doesn't have any TFS databases, install using the application-tier only installation type, restore your backed-up databases then use tfsconfig remapdbs from the commandline to set the right database server, service account etc. See [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware) for details.

In you case, you are trying to move/copy the collection to another server. So you need to detach the collection first. See [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection) for details.

You cannot attach a database backup of a TFS database that wasn't detached before. Detached collection database should have TFS_SNAPSHOT_STATE extended attribute set to Complete. If this attribute does not exist then collection is not detached and it cannot be attached.

---

**UPDATE:**

You have to detach to backup then restore to attach if you want to replicate a project collection in another TFS, just exactly following [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection).

If you just require the only one project, you have two ways to do that:

- Create a new team project within the existing collection, then add
  the existing specific project to source control, then check in the
  project to the new TFS.
- If you want to keep the source control history, then you need to
  [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection) to the TFS, then delete other
  projects, just keep the project you needed.

Comment: Thanks Andy, in my case I want to replicate a project collection in another TFS for data clean up (we require only one project from that collection). I do not want to use a detach & attach method. Will executing the commands of Preclone, ChangeServerID & RemapDBs in new TFS instance cause any issue on the live TFS server (Current server)?

Comment: @dia Unfortunately you have to detach to backup then restore to attach if you want to replicate a project collection in another TFS, exactly following [Move a team project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection). If you just require the only one project, you can just check in the project to the new TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you verify if below steps should help in me in completing the task.

1) Stop the TFS services in Current server  
2) Stop the colelction in Current server  
3) Detach the collection from Current server  
4) Take the SQL backup of the collection in Current server  
5) Copy the SQL backup to New server  
6) Re-attach the collection in Current server, and get the environment online  
7) Restore the SQL backup in New Server  
8) Attach the collection in New server  
9) Verify the required project data  
10) Projects clean up in New server

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Marked as answer.

Comment: One more query, in case of Split Project Collection, if collection is detached from one TFS instance (re-attached after backup) and restored to new TFS instance, will there be any open connections between the SQL like cross writings or corruptions ?

Comment: @dia When you detach a collection, all jobs and services are stopped, and then the collection database is stopped, So the connection will be lost. The connection will be available again once re-attached completed, Nothing serious, system will auto-sync the data periodically between collection and warehouse database.